# Field that is a subfield of own of its subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ and $L$ be fields. We have homomorphisms $f: K \to L$ and $g: L \to K$. Are $K$ and $L$ necessarily isomorphic?

Comment: Do these homomorphisms send $1$ to $1$ ?

Comment: @lhf For fields that condition is automatic.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, is it? Can't you send $1$ (and everything else) to $0$ ?

Comment: @lhf Ohh, right (I assumed non-trivial since otherwise the question is trivial, but that should probably be specified).

Comment: yes, all of my field-homomorphisms send 1 to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *no*.

Here is a counterexample from [*The Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Property in Categories*](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Laackman.pdf) by Don Laackman:

[image]

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89718/classes-of-fields-and-cantor-schröder-bernstein.

Answer (score 3):

let $K$ be the field of meromorphic functions periodic with periods $1$ and $i$,
and let $L$ be the field of meromorphic functions periodic with periods $2$ and $i$.

We have an obvious inclusion $L \to K$, and a scaling map $K \to L$ ($f \mapsto x \mapsto f(x/2)$)

However since they are the function fields of non-equivalent elliptic curves, I don't think $K$ and $L$ are isomorphic.